# How to convert XML to a DataTable C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have following output of xml response. How can I convert this xml data to a data table in c#.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <correlationId xmlns:ns4="http://www.crifbuergel.de/bone_v4" xmlns:ns3="http://www.crifbuergel.de/bone_v3" xmlns:ns2="http://www.crifbuergel.de/bone_v2" xmlns="http://www.crifbuergel.de/bone_v1">002</correlationId>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <searchResponse xmlns="http://www.crifbuergel.de/bone_v1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.crifbuergel.de/bone_v2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.crifbuergel.de/bone_v3" xmlns:ns4="http://www.crifbuergel.de/bone_v4">
         <candidate>
            <identifier>
               <type>VAT</type>
               <value>DE666814999</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
               <type>ONR</type>
               <value>26120001</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
               <type>TAX_ID</type>
               <value>5333044444444</value>
            </identifier>
            <registry>
               <type>HRB</type>
               <number>1234</number>
               <city>Hamburg</city>
            </registry>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Möbelhaus Peter Neumann GmbH</name>
            <location>
               <street>Seewartenstr.</street>
               <house>9</house>
               <city>Hamburg</city>
               <zip>20459</zip>
               <country>
                  <code>DEU</code>
                  <text>Deutschland</text>
               </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>HEADOFFICE</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>100</similarity>
         </candidate>
         <candidate>
            <identifier>
               <type>VAT</type>
               <value>DE123456789</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
               <type>ONR</type>
               <value>11498001</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
               <type>TAX_ID</type>
               <value>5123012341234</value>
            </identifier>
            <registry>
               <type>HRB</type>
               <number>1268</number>
               <city>Aachen</city>
            </registry>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Möbelhaus Peter Neumann AG</name>
            <location>
               <street>Adalbertsteinweg</street>
               <house>26</house>
               <city>Aachen</city>
               <zip>52070</zip>
               <country>
                  <code>DEU</code>
                  <text>Deutschland</text>
               </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>HEADOFFICE</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>84</similarity>
         </candidate>
         <candidate>
            <identifier>
               <type>ONR</type>
               <value>31621001</value>
            </identifier>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Peter Neumann</name>
            <location>
               <street>Friedensallee</street>
               <house>254</house>
               <city>Hamburg</city>
               <zip>22763</zip>
               <country>
                  <code>DEU</code>
                  <text>Deutschland</text>
               </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>BRANCH</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>84</similarity>
         </candidate>
         <candidate>
            <identifier>
               <type>ONR</type>
               <value>42076150</value>
            </identifier>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Möbelhaus Peter Neumann GmbH</name>
            <location>
               <street>Waldstr.</street>
               <house>5</house>
               <city>Pinneberg</city>
               <zip>25421</zip>
               <country>
                  <code>DEU</code>
                  <text>Deutschland</text>
               </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>BRANCH</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>84</similarity>
         </candidate>
         <candidate>
            <identifier>
               <type>VAT</type>
               <value>DE123437641</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
               <type>ONR</type>
               <value>19276000</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
               <type>TAX_ID</type>
               <value>5333044444444</value>
            </identifier>
            <registry>
               <type>HRB</type>
               <number>1268</number>
            </registry>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Möbelhaus Peter Neumann - Negativ GmbH - Basisdaten Nachtragstest</name>
            <location>
               <street>Friedlandstr.</street>
               <house>2</house>
               <city>Aachen</city>
               <zip>52064</zip>
               <country>
                  <code>DEU</code>
                  <text>Deutschland</text>
               </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>HEADOFFICE</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>83</similarity>
         </candidate>
         <candidate>
            <identifier>
               <type>ONR</type>
               <value>12425003</value>
            </identifier>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Peter Neumann</name>
            <location>
               <street>Holzgraben</street>
               <house>24</house>
               <city>Aachen</city>
               <zip>52062</zip>
               <country>
                  <code>DEU</code>
                  <text>Deutschland</text>
               </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>HEADOFFICE</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>81</similarity>
         </candidate>
         <candidate>
            <identifier>
               <type>ONR</type>
               <value>42046616</value>
            </identifier>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Neumann GmbH</name>
            <location>
               <street>Paul-Ehrlich-Str.</street>
               <house>5a</house>
               <city>Dietzenbach</city>
               <zip>63128</zip>
               <country>
                  <code>DEU</code>
                  <text>Deutschland</text>
               </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>HEADOFFICE</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>81</similarity>
         </candidate>
         <candidate>
            <identifier>
               <type>ONR</type>
               <value>42075283</value>
            </identifier>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Peter Neumann</name>
            <location>
               <street>Eisenstockstr.</street>
               <house>12</house>
               <city>Ettlingen</city>
               <zip>76275</zip>
               <country>
                  <code>DEU</code>
                  <text>Deutschland</text>
               </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>HEADOFFICE</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>81</similarity>
         </candidate>
         <candidate>
            <identifier>
               <type>ONR</type>
               <value>25189001</value>
            </identifier>
            <registry>
               <type>HRB</type>
               <number>1269</number>
            </registry>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Max Mustermann GmbH</name>
            <location>
               <street>Gasstr.</street>
               <house>18</house>
               <city>Hamburg</city>
               <zip>22761</zip>
               <country>
                  <code>DEU</code>
                  <text>Deutschland</text>
               </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>HEADOFFICE</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>80</similarity>
         </candidate>
      </searchResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried like below, But DataTable contains no row:

```
string xmlData = txtResponse.Text;
        XElement x = XElement.Parse(xmlData);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        XElement setup = (from p in x.Descendants() select p).First();
        foreach (XElement xe in setup.Descendants()) // build your DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(xe.Name.ToString(), typeof(string))); // add columns to your dt
        var all = from p in x.Descendants(setup.Name.ToString()) select p;
        foreach (XElement xe in all)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (XElement xe2 in xe.Descendants())
                dr[xe2.Name.ToString()] = xe2.Value; //add in the values
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
```

Comment: Looks more like a DataSet than a DataTable. Can you show what the Schema of a single DataTable should be, in your view? -- Note that `[DataSet].ReadXml()` in `XmlReadMode.InferSchema` mode can generate a relational data set, inferring the schema and also generating the required PK / FK in each table

Comment: You get this envelope from some service, right? Does this service provide its description in the form of a wsdl?  If so, generate a set of C# classes based on it and work with them. Then forget about raw XML and enjoy strict typing.

Comment: I have created proxy classes in visual studio. When I create the object of a class, this is quite strange. For example I have create object B of a class A. In next statement when I write B. (B dot) it display no properties or methods associated with A class. I also have to assign this object B as property of another class.  If I mouse hover object B, in tooltip it says make field readonly. This behavior is for each object of each class. Why is it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to flatten your data

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(x);

JArray jArr = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("soap:Envelope.soap:Body.searchResponse.candidate");

// converting JArray to DataTable
var jArrFlat = new JArray();
foreach (JObject jObj in jArr)
{
    var jo = new JObject();
    foreach (var prop in jObj.Properties())
    {
        if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            for (var i = 0; i < prop.Value.Count(); i++)
            {
                JObject jO = (JObject)prop.Value[i];
                foreach (var p in jO.Properties())
                    jo.Add(new JProperty(prop.Name + i.ToString() + "-" + p.Name, p.Value));
            }
        else if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            if (prop.Name != "identifier")
                foreach (var p in ((JObject)prop.Value).Properties())
                {
                    if (p.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object)
                        jo.Add(new JProperty(prop.Name + "-" + p.Name, p.Value));
                    else
                        foreach (var pp in ((JObject)p.Value).Properties())
                            jo.Add(new JProperty(prop.Name + "-" + p.Name + "-" + pp.Name, pp.Value));
                }
            else
                foreach (var p in ((JObject)prop.Value).Properties())
                    jo.Add(new JProperty(prop.Name + "0" + "-" + p.Name, p.Value));
        }
        else jo.Add(new JProperty(prop.Name, prop.Value));
    }
    jArrFlat.Add(jo);
}
DataTable dt = jArrFlat.ToObject<DataTable>();
```

or it is much easier to convert it to a c# List

```
    List<Data> identifiers = jArr.ToObject<List<Data>>();

public class Data
{
    public List<Identifier> identifiers { get; set; }
    public Registry registry { get; set; }
    public string hitType { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string unitType { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string similarity { get; set; }

    public Data(JToken identifier)
    {
        if (identifier.Type == JTokenType.Array) identifiers = identifier.ToObject<List<Identifier>>();
        else identifiers = new List<Identifier> { identifier.ToObject<Identifier>() };
    }
}

public class Identifier
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string house { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public Country country { get; set; }
}

public class Registry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement searchResponse = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "searchResponse").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = searchResponse.GetDefaultNamespace();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Ident 1 Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ident 1 Value", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ident 2 Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ident 2 Value", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ident 3 Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ident 3 Value", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("Registry Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Registry Number", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Registry City", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("Hit Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("Street", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("House", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ZIP", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Country Code", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Similarity", typeof(int));

            foreach(XElement candidate in doc.Descendants(ns + "candidate"))
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                List<XElement> identifiers = candidate.Elements(ns + "identifier").ToList();
                for(int i = 1; i <= identifiers.Count; i++)
                {
                    newRow["Ident " + i + " Type"] = (string)identifiers[i - 1].Element(ns + "type");
                    newRow["Ident " + i + " Value"] = (string)identifiers[i - 1].Element(ns + "value");
                }

                XElement registry = candidate.Element(ns + "registry");
                if (registry != null)
                {
                    newRow["Registry Type"] = (string)registry.Element(ns + "type");
                    newRow["Registry Number"] = (int)registry.Element(ns + "number");
                    newRow["Registry City"] = (string)registry.Element(ns + "city");
                }

                XElement hitType = candidate.Element(ns + "hitType");
                newRow["Hit Type"] = (string)hitType;
                XElement name = candidate.Element(ns + "name");
                newRow["Name"] = (string)name;

                XElement location = candidate.Element(ns + "location");
                newRow["Street"] = (string)location.Element(ns + "street");
                newRow["House"] = (string)location.Element(ns + "house");
                newRow["City"] = (string)location.Element(ns + "city");
                newRow["Zip"] = (int)location.Element(ns + "zip");
                newRow["Country Code"] = (string)location.Descendants(ns + "code").FirstOrDefault();
                newRow["Country"] = (string)location.Descendants(ns + "text").FirstOrDefault();


                XElement unitType = candidate.Element(ns + "unitType");
                newRow["Unit"] = (string)unitType;
                XElement status = candidate.Element(ns + "status");
                newRow["Status"] = (string)status;
                XElement similarity = candidate.Element(ns + "similarity");
                newRow["Similarity"] = (int)similarity;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Results

[image]