# Convert multi sub nodes XML into DataTable

Tags: c#, xml

Good day,
I am having following and more similar like this XML strings as result from SOAP request. This xml contains multi-level nodes. How can I convert this to DataTable using C#.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
    <correlationId xmlns:ns4="http://www.abc.de/abc_v4"
                   xmlns:ns3="http://www.abc.de/abc_v3"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://www.abc.de/abc_v2"
                   xmlns="http://www.abc.de/bone_v1">100</correlationId>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <searchResponse xmlns="http://www.abc.de/abc_v1"
                    xmlns:ns2="http://www.abc.de/abc_v2"
                    xmlns:ns3="http://www.abc.de/abc_v3"
                    xmlns:ns4="http://www.abc.de/abc_v4">
        <candidate>
            <identifier>
                <type>VAT</type>
                <value>DE123437641</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
                <type>ONR</type>
                <value>19276000</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
                <type>TAX_ID</type>
                <value>5333044444444</value>
            </identifier>
            <registry>
                <type>HRB</type>
                <number>1268</number>
            </registry>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Möbelhaus Peter Neumann - Negativ GmbH - Basisdaten Nachtragstest</name>
            <location>
                <street>Friedlandstr.</street>
                <house>2</house>
                <city>Aachen</city>
                <zip>52064</zip>
                <country>
                    <code>DEU</code>
                    <text>Deutschland</text>
                </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>HEADOFFICE</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>100</similarity>
        </candidate>
        <candidate>
            <identifier>
                <type>VAT</type>
                <value>DE666814999</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
                <type>ONR</type>
                <value>26120001</value>
            </identifier>
            <identifier>
                <type>TAX_ID</type>
                <value>5333044444444</value>
            </identifier>
            <registry>
                <type>HRB</type>
                <number>1234</number>
                <city>Hamburg</city>
            </registry>
            <hitType>COMPANY</hitType>
            <name>Möbelhaus Peter Neumann GmbH</name>
            <location>
                <street>Seewartenstr.</street>
                <house>9</house>
                <city>Hamburg</city>
                <zip>20459</zip>
                <country>
                    <code>DEU</code>
                    <text>Deutschland</text>
                </country>
            </location>
            <unitType>HEADOFFICE</unitType>
            <status>active</status>
            <similarity>100</similarity>
        </candidate>
    </searchResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

</soap:Envelope>

I can convert single level nodes to data table. It's quite simple. But multilevel nodes are problem. For example one node is Location. This Location is a class in data models. But end user's requirement is simple. He wants this XML as DataTable as an input into his model.
Please suggest a suitable solution.
Thanks

Comment: *He wants this XML as DataTable as an input into his model.* -- has the end user specified his required column type for `<location>`?  I would suggest you ask for this.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76956657/11392290? It is not a good idea to repeat your question over and over again with any feedback. Sooner or later people stop to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to flatten your data

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    XElement xe = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "searchResponse").FirstOrDefault();

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xe, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,true);

    var jArr = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("candidate");

    jArr = new JArray(jArr.Select(jObj => new JObject(((JObject)jObj).Properties()
                  .Descendants()
                  .Where(d => d.Type != JTokenType.Object
                         && d.Type != JTokenType.Array)
                  .Select(o => o.Path.Substring(o.Path.IndexOf(".") + 1))
                  .Distinct()
                  .Select(o => new JProperty(o.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), jObj.SelectToken(o)))
                  .Where(n => n.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object))));

    DataTable dt = jArr.ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc =  XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement searchResponse = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "searchResponse").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = searchResponse.GetDefaultNamespace();

            int maxIdentifieres = searchResponse.Elements(ns + "candidate").Max(x => x.Elements(ns + "identifier").Count());

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 1; i <= maxIdentifieres; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("Identifer Type " + i, typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Identifer Value " + i, typeof(string));
            }
            dt.Columns.Add("Registry Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Registry Number", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Hit Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Street", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("House", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Zip", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Country Code", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Unit Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Similarity", typeof(int));

            foreach(XElement canidate in searchResponse.Elements(ns + "candidate"))
            {
                DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
                List<XElement> identifiers = canidate.Elements(ns + "identifier").ToList();
                for(int i = 1; i <= identifiers.Count; i++)
                {
                    row["Identifer Type " + i] = (string)identifiers[i - 1].Element(ns + "type");
                    row["Identifer Value " + i] = (string)identifiers[i - 1].Element(ns + "value");
                }

                XElement registry = canidate.Element(ns + "registry");
                row["Registry Type"] = (string)registry.Element(ns + "type");
                row["Registry Number"] = (int)registry.Element(ns + "number");

                row["Hit Type"] = (string)canidate.Element(ns + "hitType");
                row["Name"] = (string)canidate.Element(ns + "name");

                XElement location = canidate.Element(ns + "location");
                row["Street"] = (string)location.Element(ns + "street");
                row["House"] = (string)location.Element(ns + "house");
                row["City"] = (string)location.Element(ns + "city");
                row["Zip"] = (string)location.Element(ns + "zip");
                row["Country Code"] = (string)location.Descendants(ns + "code").FirstOrDefault();
                row["Country"] = (string)location.Descendants(ns + "text").FirstOrDefault();

                row["Unit Type"] = (string)canidate.Element(ns + "unitType");
                row["Status"] = (string)canidate.Element(ns + "status");
                row["Similarity"] = (string)canidate.Element(ns + "similarity");
            }
        }
    }

}
```